# carousel bootstrap slider firefox

Tags: firefox, carousel

I'd be grateful if you could help me. I use a CSS3 bootstrap carousel slideshow. Slideshow appears in the following link.
It works fine in google chrome but unfortunately it doesn't work in mozilla firefox or internet explorer. I use -moz and -webkit css3 tricks but not working..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aris2134/cg1qk1ne/4/

Comment: In addition the slider has some problems. For example, when slides left or right, it displays a background color behind images.. Any ideas in order to fix these problems?